# How do I create a purchase activity plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

How do I create an user activity plot using matplotlib. I have looked at other similar answers on stack overflow but none of them answer my question well.

My pandas data frame looks something like below:

```
 user | purchase date | item
-------------------------------
  x   |  7/1/2010     | AAA
  y   |  8/2/2010     | BBB
  x   |  7/2/2010     | CCC
  z   |  8/4/2010     | AAA
  z   |  8/1/2010     | DDD
```

I want something like this:

```
(users on y-axis)
x: |----X-X----------------------------------------
y: |-----------------X-----------------------------
z: |---------------X----X--------------------------
---|------------------------------------------------------->
            time(I want dates to be in my x-axis)
```

My aim is to visualize customer's purchase activities. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the `user` column to a unique numeric value per `user`, which allows you to simply plot it and then just change the tick labels.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.purchase_date)

users = df.user.unique()
d = dict((users[i], i) for i in range(len(users)))
df['user_id'] = df.user.map(d)

ax = df.plot(x='purchase_date', y='user_id', lw=0, marker='x', ms=6, legend=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(users), 1))
ax.set_yticklabels(users)
plt.ylabel('user')
_ = plt.show()
```

[image]

Note, my choice to use a line plot with `lw=0` instead of scatter is important, as `df.plot(kind='scatter')` cannot handle `datetime` objects for the x-axis and you have to jump through a lot of hoops to get it correct.